# About the proof of the Lindeberg-Feller theorem.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I found this [pdf](http://www.utstat.toronto.edu/keith/eco2402/clt.pdf) online that proves the Lindeberg-Feller theorem (Theorem 3.4.5) in probability Theory with the proof on page 2. At an early stage in the proof the author defines the Independent random variables $$Y_{n,i}$$
such that they are Independent of $$X_{n,i}$$ and with the property that $$Y_{n,i} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\mathbb{E}(X_{n,i})).$$
Why do such $Y_{n,i}$'s exist? I read in my own lecture notes that one can expand the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ to assure existence, but I cannot figure out why.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $X$ is a random variable living on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathsf{P})$ and $F$ is a CDF (e.g. $\mathcal{N}(0,\mathsf{E}X^2)$ in your case). First, consider a product space $(\Omega\times \mathbb{R},\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}},\mathsf{P}\otimes \mu_F)$, where $\mu_F$ is a probability measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}})$ s.t. $\mu_F((-\infty,x]=F(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $X'$ and $Y$ defined on the latter space by $X'(\omega,x)=X(\omega)$ and $Y(\omega, x)=x$ are independent, the law of $X'$ conincides with that of $X$, and the CDF of $Y$ is $F$.